# sencha touch loading spinner not animating in ios 9

Tags: sencha-touch, ios9

My sencha touch application built with cordova 3.6.0.In iOS<=8 sencha touch loading mask(Ext.LoadMask) worked absolutely fine. After release of iOS9, LoadMask is not animating at all, instead it just struck. Ajax requests are working but loading spinning is not animating.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faced the same issue

Removing the '-ms-' from @keyframes had fixed the issue for me.

Source https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?301331-Chrome-v43-Ext.LoadMask-is-no-longer-animated

Use this css:

@keyframes x-loading-spinner-rotate{0%{transform:rotate(0deg)}8.32%{transform:rotate(0deg)}8.33%{transform:rotate(30deg)}16.65%{transform:rotate(30deg)}16.66%{transform:rotate(60deg)}24.99%{transform:rotate(60deg)}25%{transform:rotate(90deg)}33.32%{transform:rotate(90deg)}33.33%{transform:rotate(120deg)}41.65%{transform:rotate(120deg)}41.66%{transform:rotate(150deg)}49.99%{transform:rotate(150deg)}50%{transform:rotate(180deg)}58.32%{transform:rotate(180deg)}58.33%{transform:rotate(210deg)}66.65%{transform:rotate(210deg)}66.66%{transform:rotate(240deg)}74.99%{transform:rotate(240deg)}75%{transform:rotate(270deg)}83.32%{transform:rotate(270deg)}83.33%{transform:rotate(300deg)}91.65%{transform:rotate(300deg)}91.66%{transform:rotate(330deg)}100%{transform:rotate(330deg)}}